# How do I convert scientific notation string to float in PHP?

Tags: php, numbers, scientific-notation, notation

I have written a CSV importer and some of the values are very small, for example, in one of the CSVs I have 0.000024 which is being formatted as "2.40E-05" and when PHP puts that into the database it stores it as 2.4, I found an article that said if you add 1 to it, it changes to a float which is what I did and I got 1.000024, but if I then subtract 1, it goes back to being 2.4E-05, what is the best way in PHP to convert a scientific notation string to an actual float value? I would like to be able to store the value in my database as 0.000024.

Comment: I think you're slightly confused. What you see as output isn't necessarily the same as how a number is stored internally in PHP. For instance, see [this example](https://3v4l.org/LC2pl), where the output looks the same as the string that went in, it is still a real float. This means that when you look at the output of your database, it might be a real float, but the output might be in the scientific notation.

Comment: _"and when PHP puts that into the database it stores it as 2.4"_ - and how _exactly_ did you do that, and what is the column type? MySQL has no problem understanding this format, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/number-literals.html - `SELECT 2.40E-05` gets you `0.000024` as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert to a string otherwise if you keep the float it will keep displaying with scientific notation

```
$scientific = "1.828331E-9" ;
$num=explode('-', $scientific);
$precision=$num[1]+ strlen(filter_var($num[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT))-1;
$float = number_format($scientific, $precision);
echo "converted $float and back to original " . (float)$float;
```

Comment: Clever idea, but I think Elliott Coe has trouble understanding that if you store 2.4E-05 as a float in the database, you can always convert it to 0.000024 later on. You don't want to store floats as a string in the database for two reasons: 1. If you want to do any calculations with the string it has to be converted to a number first. 2. Floats take up less space than strings.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware on db side you have 2 options, store in float or double column and do the conversion each time, or store in decimal column and no conversion is need. 
If you chose the decimal, you must know in advance the maximum precision you need (you define it at column creation time) in order to not lose information. All the 3 columns type accept scientific notation as input. For sure, do not user varchr as it is goin to use much more space.